# 1Gbit/s dedicated connection in Seattle is enough for Asia and America?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, datacenter, network-speed

I want to provide good quality web service to Eastern-Asia and America. Is 1Gbit/s in Seattle sufficient for common web applications and (if possible) real-time messaging, or I should consider another location in US?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more detail.  Are you an ISP providing internet service?  Are you hosting sites that will be available to those locations?

Answer (score 2):

Seattle has several underwater cables landing near it. Portland is about as well connected and is also close to the landing point of the Australia cable ([cable map](http://www.telegeography.com/product-info/map_cable/images/cable_map_2010_large.png)). Seattle, Portland, or the Los Angeles area are good choices for low latency access to the US and Asia.

Comment: That link has expired. http://www.submarinecablemap.com/ might be a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I own a hosting company with three data centers.  1GB is very fast.  But as other said, a single server can consume that BW.  I can say, generally speaking, that 1GB is very fast and I would almost ask if you really need that much for "common web applications."  We started out with T3 circuits (45MB circuits) and we now run MPLS+Ethernet.  We monitor our BW and purchase as needed.  I would look to peer with a provider that allows you to grow this way.  We use NTT and Level3.

Answer (score 1):

There's literally no way of knowing this, your cable might go straight to your customers or straight into a bucket of water - you really have no idea with such little information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're hosting websites the bandwidth you need for connecting to the Internet backbone (I'm assuming the connection is to the backbone) will depend on the amount of traffic you expect.  It also depends on the payload size of that traffic.  Streaming multimedia for example requires more bandwidth with low latency.  Some in house testing may help.  The northwest should serve well for your target audience.